# Javascript function doesn't work on all browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have created a `fnNumericDecimalOnly` function Javascript,
and using it in my jsp page which allow only Numbers and decimal not other than that like in below code.

Code:

```js
function fnNumericDecimalOnly(event) {     
    if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 58) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback required-field-block">
        <label for="inTimeTxt" class="col-md-4 control-label">In Time</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">

            <input id="inTimeTxt" name="inTimeTxt" class="form-control" maxlength="5"
                   type="text" placeholder="00:00" value="" title="In Time" 
                   onkeypress="javascript:return fnNumericDecimalOnly(event)" 
                   data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" />(In hh:mm format)

            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" id="inTimeTxtMessage"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working only in Chrome but not in Firefox.
So can anyone help me? What can I do so that it works for all browsers?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very poor problem statement. Do some basic debugging. Are errors reported on the console? Does the function get called at all? Does `event.keyCode` have the value you expect?

Comment: Having your JS and HTML in **completely different** code snippets is really unhelpful. They won't interact at all!

Comment: why did you tag this with [tag:jsp] and [tag:jquery]? I see neither in the code. Only include tags *relevant* to your problem.

Comment: Can't you just use `input type="time"`? Or two `input type="number"` inputs for older browsers

Comment: @Quentin my javaScript function is in file which is a collection of many different js functions. i have imported in my .jsp file and used the function name in different fields.

Comment: @LalitDubey — That comment doesn't seem to related to any of my comments.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp

Note: In Firefox, the keyCode property does not work on the onkeypress event (will only return 0). For a cross-browser solution, use the which property together with keyCode, e.g:

```
var x = event.which || event.keyCode;  // Use either which or keyCode, depending on browser support
```

It's a 5s google search thing...

```
function fnNumericDecimalOnly(event) { 
    let key = event.which || event.keyCode;     
    if (key < 45 || key > 58) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MrAleister, my concern is to write the code at one js file and use with many fields in my jsp page. so for that i need to write a code which should work with every browsers. so can you tell me please how to do it?

Comment: I just did - update your `fnNumericDecimalOnly` method.